# Why do I get a different result when I do math on a quoted vs. non-quoted variable?

Tags: perl

I am working with latitudes and longitudes to determine business locations and ran into some odd behavior.

In the Perl snippet below, the equation assigning data to `$v1` evaluates to 1. When I call `acos($v1)`, I receive a `sqrt` error. When I call `acos("$v1")` (with quotes), I do not. Calling `acos(1)` does not produce the error, either. Why do the quotes matter?

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

sub acos {
    my $rad = shift;
    return (atan2(sqrt(1 - $rad**2), $rad));
}

my $v1 = (0.520371764072297 * 0.520371764072297) +
         (0.853939826425894 * 0.853939826425894 * 1);

print acos($v1);   # Can't take sqrt of -8.88178e-16 at foo line 8.
print acos("$v1"); # 0
```

Comment: Related: [Bug #127182 for perl5: One digit short to correctly stringify a double](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127182)

Comment: See also [Why is Perl inconsistent with sprintf rounding?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41312890/2173773)

Answer (score 15):

`$v1` is not exactly 1:

```
$ perl -e'
    $v1 = (0.520371764072297 * 0.520371764072297) +
          (0.853939826425894 * 0.853939826425894 * 1);
    printf "%.16f\n", $v1
'
1.0000000000000004
```

However, when you stringify it, [Perl only keeps 15 digits of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14104687/176646):

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'
    $v1 = (0.520371764072297 * 0.520371764072297) +
          (0.853939826425894 * 0.853939826425894 * 1);
    Dump "$v1"
'
SV = PV(0x2345090) at 0x235a738
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x2353980 "1"\0      # string value is exactly 1
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 16
```

Comment: Nice resource, thank you. I searched and couldn't locate it in docs.

Comment: Thank you for your comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400902/why-does-foo-bar-autovivify-but-foo-doesnt). This is your bounty as I promise ;-)